# Change login screen styles in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: themes, login-screen, gdm, 18.10

To install theme for login screen I need to change `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. But it is not there. What is the alternative for that file in Ubuntu 18.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Ubuntu 18.10 this file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` makes the changes that you are looking for as opposed to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

18.10 lock screen after tweakings.
[image]

after few more tweakings..
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I get the `after few more tweak` code?

Comment: @PRATAP which line allows us to change the dull purple background ?

Comment: @PRATAP  Thanks, it works. How to make the icon border round ?

Comment: Also, in 18.04 when we bootup, the screen will have a background an orange panel with our username in it. We need to click on it to login. Is there any way we can customize this striking orange ?

Comment: The user symbol which is round in your screenshot while square in my PC.